# Set up second router behind router, block internet access on second router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, iot

I want to block my 'dumb' IoT devices from accessing the internet but they have to be accessible on my LAN.

I have my providers router/modem and was thinking to connect a second router by connecting a LAN to WAN of second router. The Second router has OpenWrt and can be configured extensively.

I find a lot of info on the net but no answer that takes into account all the variables I want to control:

I want
- IoT devices are connected via wifi on the second router
- IoT devices accessible for the device (read: google home) on my main router to send them the on/off signal. 
- Home app to see the IoT devices while my smartphone is connected to the first router for internet access

Is this manageable with two routers like I proposed, and if yes how, or should I be thinking about a Vlan?

Comment: I’m not familiar with google home but there are two very bi questions to answer. Do the devices all check in to a cloud service to communicate and/or communicate directly with each other on the network? And, do the devices all need to be on the same network to discover each other via broadcasts? My gut tells me your proposed solution is problematic. I certainly wouldn’t do it that way. I would assign those devices (via DHCP) a static set of IP addresses and then block that range of IPs at the gateway with a firewall.

Comment: The hardest part of your request is figuring out how to allow *some, but not all* traffic to go between your main home network and your IoT network. You'd have to figure out exactly what that traffic looks like and come up with firewall rules that lets that kind of traffic through.

Comment: Ok, not as straight forward as I thought. @Appleoddity I'll consider the static ip adresses. They communicate via WIFI. Is it possible to make a second subnet and only allow traffic to and from the main subnet but prevent internet communication on the second subnet? I just want to prevent hackers from reaching and using my IoT devices